# React ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react and I can't get around how to make a listview scrollable.

I have the following rendering code:

```
<ScrollableTabView tabBarPosition="top">
      <ScrollView tabLabel="List View" style={styles.tabView}>  
        {this.renderListView()} 
       </ScrollView>
</ScrollableTabView>
```

and this is how the renderListView looks like:

```
 renderListView() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                    style      = {styles.listview}
                    renderRow  = {this.renderRow}
                  //  renderSectionHeader = {this.renderSectionHeader}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

and renderRow:

```
Object.assign(Two.prototype, {
    bindableMethods : {
        renderRow : function (rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressRow(rowData, sectionID)}>
                    <View style={styles.rowStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.day} {":"} {rowData.date}</Text>  
                        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{"Place:"} {rowData.place_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }
});
```

The problem here is my listview doesn't scroll and I can't understand why it has the behaviour it has.
Any tips/ideas why this code might not work and what would be a right solution?
I am using react 0.32.0

Comment: please, add the method `this.renderRow`

Comment: why do u need the `scrollView` that wrap the `{this.renderListView()}`?

Comment: try setting `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}` on the innermost scrollview (ListView extends ScrollView FYI)